# Completely new to Python. Unable to understand a lines of code written below

Tags: python

I am having difficulty understanding the following lines of Python code. The code is written to find the vowels contained in the word "milliways".

```
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u']
word = "milliways"
found = []
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        if letter not in found:
            found.append(letter)
for vowel in found:
    print(vowel)
```

Can someone please help me understand the code above.

Comment: Please reformat your code so it works. (Indentation)

Comment: SO is not a programming school. Most of the lines are extremely simple, even a beginner should be able to understand them. Could you be more explicit about what you don't understand?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. This website is not a tutorial service. We have to assume some minimal level of understanding of the language.

Comment: If you don't understand what `word = "milliways"` does, you need to pick up a Python tutorial and learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback...Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the first 3 lines of code we first create a list of letters (vowels) to search for, define a word to search for vowels in, and create an empty array where we will store vowels found.

Next we iterate through each letter of the word we chose and check it the letter is a vowel and not already in the list with found vowels, if those criteria are met, we add the vowel to the "found" list.

In the last 2 lines of code we just loop through the list of found vowels and print them out to actually see which vowels we found in the word.

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments to your code so that you can see what's going on

```
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u'] # this declares a list of vowels
word = "milliways" # declares an input word
found = [] # used to store list of vowels in word

for letter in word: # iterates through every character in word
    if letter in vowels: # checks if character is in the vowels list
        if letter not in found: 
            found.append(letter) # if the character is a vowel, and not in found list it adds it

for vowel in found: # prints list of vowels in word
    print(vowel)
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick and Usernamenotfound , for the explanation.